# Querying string array with gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to select items of a table with a column of type `text[]`.
The result of the field `brandIds` always return `null`

my struct:

```
type User struct {
    Email    string         `json:"email"`
    Name     string         `json:"name"`
    BrandIds pq.StringArray `gorm:"type:text[]" json:"brandIds"`
}
```

the code:

```
        var users []dtos.User
        db.Table("user").Find(&users)
        data, _ := json.Marshal(users)
```

Name and emails returns fine... But the `brandIds` always return null.
Type of brandIds column is `text[]`

Comment: Are you checking for errors from `db.Find` and `json.Marshal`? I cannot reproduce this from using your code, so the error must be due to something that you haven't posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres have some troubles with camelCase column names. When I named `BrandIds` gorm was looking for column `bran_id`

I needed to specify the column name so I have added the `gorm:"column:brandId"` to tell gorm whats the name of the column.